# How to Configure CGI in Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, cgi

I recently installed Apache2 on Ubuntu and I am trying to configure CGI. I added the following lines in apache2.conf file:

```
ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/ /home/router/cgi-bin/

<Directory /home/router/cgi-bin/>
        Options ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
</Directory>
```

And I saved and restart apache2, but when I type the following in browser:

```
http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/file1.cgi
```

I get the following error:

```
You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/file1.cgi on this server.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Apache CGI support with the following commands:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You also do not need the AddHandler line as it is, as your .cgi extension is not a .pl file.

I recommend your to do do too:

ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/ /home/router/cgi-bin/

```
<Directory /home/router/cgi-bin>
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```